# Python numerical operations on dictionaries having tuple keys of strings and integers

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary, integer, tuples

First question here, I'm kinda new to Python data structures.

After stock options orders I'm provided with those two dictionaries (example):

```py
price = {('GOOGL', 0): 45.75, ('GOOGL', 1): 45.57, ('TSLA', 0): 39.41, ('TSLA', 1): 39.31, ('TSLA', 2): 39.55, ('TSLA', 3): 39.39}
quantity = {('GOOGL', 0): 2.0, ('GOOGL', 1): 1.0, ('TSLA', 0): 1.0, ('TSLA', 1): 1.0, ('TSLA', 2): 4.0, ('TSLA', 3): 2.0}
```

The first is prices for each execution and the second is quantities for each execution.

Can't seem to find a way to access the prices and quantities with tuple keys and I would like to calculate the average price of each option in order to get a structure that I can access, like this for example:

```py
average_price = {'GOOGL': 45.69, 'TSLA': 39.46}
```

What would be steps?

Thank you!

Q

Comment: Please format the code. Thnak you very much

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions György, I simplified to highlight code only. Q

Answer (score 0):

This working code will show you how to process the price dictionary:

```
price = {('GOOGL', 0): 45.75,
         ('GOOGL', 1): 45.57,
         ('TSLA', 0): 39.41,
         ('TSLA', 1): 39.31,
         ('TSLA', 2): 39.55,
         ('TSLA', 3): 39.39}

sum_dict = {}
avg_dict = {}

# Populate sum_dict with price sums, count, and calc avgs per ticker
for price_key, price_value in price.items():
    ticker = price_key[0]
    if not ticker in sum_dict.keys():
        sum_dict[ticker] = [0.0, 0, 0.0]
    sum_dict[ticker][0] += price_value
    sum_dict[ticker][1] += 1
    sum_dict[ticker][2] = sum_dict[ticker][0] / sum_dict[ticker][1]

# Tranfer avg data to avg_dict
for sum_key in sum_dict.keys():
    avg_dict[sum_key] = sum_dict[sum_key][2]
print('Per Ticker Price Avgs:', avg_dict)
```

If you need further assistance completing the processing of the quantity dictionary then let me know but the technique is roughly the same.

Comment: Hi Scott!
You didn't use the quantity dictionary to multiply the prices:
```python
quantity = {('GOOGL', 0): 2.0, ('GOOGL', 1): 1.0, ('TSLA', 0): 1.0, ('TSLA', 1): 1.0, ('TSLA', 2): 4.0, ('TSLA', 3): 2.0}
```
But that's ok, I get the method and will be able to implement it.
Thank you very much!
Q

Comment: QuantX, you're right!  I'm sorry - oversight.  I'm glad you were able to absorb the technique. Let me know if you need further help completing this...